# Can a virgin Muslim man marry a non-virgin (by premarital sex) unmarried Muslim woman?

Tags: sharia, nikah, zina

Can a virgin Muslim man/woman marry a non-virgin unmarried Muslim woman/man.

That is the man/woman who have had premarital sex which is not allowed/haram by the Islamic law.

Can this type of person marry good virgin Muslim?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Generally, it's not allowed for a believer to marry anyone who has had premarital sex.

Allah said in Surah al Noor 24:3 =

> "The fornicator does not marry except a fornicator or polytheist, and none marries her except a fornicator or a polytheist, and that has been made unlawful to the believers."

However, if the person makes toubah and asks for forgiveness, then the sin is not held against them.  Because Allah said in Surah aali-Imran 3:135=

> "And those who, when they commit an immorality or wrong themselves, remember Allah and seek forgiveness for their sins - and who can forgive sins except Allah ? - and do not persist in what they have done while they know."

And there are many similar verses.  If repentance and forgiveness is asked by the sinner, than marriage can take place between a non-fornicator and a fornicator (premarital sex).

**Now the issue with virgins**, you have to understand being a non-virgin doesn't mean the person is a fornicator.  People who have sex while married are non-virgin and still considered pure and not fornicators.

So it makes no difference if the person is a virgin or a non-virgin.

Answer (score 3):

Yes they can.

Take the examples from Prophet Muhammad (PBUH). The first wife of Prophet is `Khadijah bint Khuwaylid` (May Allah be pleased with her) who is a non-virgin.

Respectively Prophet's **10 out of 11** wives were non-virgins except for Aisha (May Allah be pleased with her).

*Islam never prevented Muslims from marrying non-virgin Muslims if the marriage is fulfilling all the rules about a marriage in Islam.*

Comment: I suggest that you give another example, since it's not agreed among all historians that Khadijah Bint Khuwaylid (May Allah be pleased with her) was married to people before the Prophet.

Comment: Please see the update, I was wrong in description.

Answer (score 0):

First thing what ever she has done in her past is haram. Having sex remembering her boyfriend . If a woman clarifies that she had boyfriend in her past right before the beginning of married life then at least husband will prepare himself for the future. Instead after marriage if he comes to know from other sources then that is the point the man decides to give talaq  or leave the girl. So better be open to things even if it hurts you

Answer (score 0):

Asalam u alaikum,
    I have red many posts regarding this matter so my conclusion is.
* She/He (non-virgin) must repent and should have asked for forgiveness from Allah. 
* If her/his past will bother you after marriage , or  makes you disrespect him/her then don't marry him/her.
* Allah is most merciful and the best at forgiveness. He is above all .
May Allah guide us all, show us right path and help us going on right path Ameen.

Answer (score -5):

i don't think you should care that much.

people make mistakes (if you consider such a thing is a mistake).

there are 7 billion people currently on this earth. if only perfect people gets to go to heaven, heaven will be an empty place.

Comment: Salam and welcome on Islam SE, we are not a usual internet forum, so we expect answers to be focused and well elaborated, therefore i strongly suggest you to add references to support your claims. For more information please consider taking our [tour], checking our [help] and read [answer] to learn how this site is supposed to work.